# How to do prime reading through a 2D array in asp pages

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

For my school project I am supposed to read values from HTML form which has 30 rows and 4 columns. 
I've made a 2d array and made the reading like this (please ignore the validation parts):

```
Sub primeRead()
    For i = 0 To 29
        cDetails(i, 0) = Request.Form("UnitCode_" & rowID+1)
        If cDetails(i,0) = " " Then
            response.write("Hello")
            Exit For
        End If
        cDetails(i, 1) = Request.Form("CP_" & rowID)
        If cDetails(i, 1) = "15" Or "20" Then
            'response.write("Credits points must be 15 or 20")
            'Exit For
        End If
        cDetails(i, 2) = Request.Form("YS_" & rowID)
        If cDetails(i, 2) = " " Then
            response.write("Hello")
            Exit For
        End If
        cDetails(i, 3) = Request.Form("UM_" & rowID)
        If cDetails(i,3) = " " Then
            response.write("Hello")
            Exit For
        End If
        rowID = rowID + 1
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

However, when I output the input taken from the form like this:

```
<%For x = 0 To 29%>
<tr>
<td> <%response.write(cDetails(x, 0))%><td/>
<td> <%response.write(cDetails(x, 1))%><td/>
<td> <%response.write(cDetails(x, 2))%><td/>
<td> <%response.write(cDetails(x, 3))%><td/>
<td> <%response.write(cDetails(x, 3))%><td/>
<tr/>
<%Next%>
```

it only shows up to 15 rows. Is there any limitations with 2D arrays VBScript or something else causing this undesirable output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how [`For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa3hh43e.aspx) loops work. The loop variable is automatically. Incrementing the variable in the loop body on top of that like you do will cause the code to skip every second row. Remove the line `i = i + 1` from the loop:

```
For i = 0 To 29
    ...
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Also, the condition `cDetails(i, 1) = "15" Or "20"` will not work the way you seem to expect. It will check if the value `cDetails(i, 1)` equals `"15"` or if the string `"20"` is true. If you want to compare a variable with more than one value you must compare the variable with each value individually:

```
If cDetails(i, 1) = "15" Or cDetails(i, 1) = "20" Then
  ...
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. +on a separate note, is it possible for you to suggest me a good documentation on vbscripting